# about CocoaPods and a Link error

Tags: ios, git, cocoapods

Thanks for view .
I'm sorry my English isn't very good.

What I did:

My company gives me a project to fix a bug, I did clone the project from github , but the project doesn't build. The project has CocoaPods, but there is only a Podfile, the Pods folder and the Podfile.lock are missing.

Podfile here :
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

```
platform :ios, '6.0'
pod 'AFNetworking'
pod 'RESideMenu'
pod 'BlocksKit'
pod 'ActionSheetPicker-3.0', '~> 1.3.5'
pod 'AppBuilder-iOS', '~> 1.3.9'
pod 'AFNetworkActivityLogger'
pod 'SwipeView'
pod 'GoogleTagManager'
pod 'MMProgressHUD'
pod 'MWPhotoBrowser', '~> 1.4.1'
pod 'WeixinActivity'
pod 'StackBluriOS'
```

I update it, but there comes a new question here: GoogleTagManager always has a connection time out, why that happen?

So I added GoogleTagManager by myself, mean I added GoogleTagManager without use CocoaPods, and delete GoogleTagManager from Podfile, and pod update.

Now I see the Pods folder and the Podfile.lock in project, so I cleaned and builded

**What I am struggling with:**

```
ld: library not found for -lPods-SwipeView
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

**Why does this error occurs?**

...help me please...Thanks...orz...,

Answer (score 0):

Chinese?
你好~

You can use it install your pod.

```
cd "Your_Project_Folder"
pod install --verbose --no-repo-update
```

http://code4app.com/article/cocoapods-install-usage

This site may be helpful to you.